# Twitter-Typeahead not autocompleting with Bloodhound

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having some issues with my code. I'm trying to use Twitter-Typeahead and Bloodhound to auto complete searches. The thing is, it's not auto completing.

Code test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Page</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="user" id="users">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/typeahead.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var users = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: 'users.php?query=%QUERY'
    });

    users.initialize();

    $('#users').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2
    }, {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'username',
        source: users.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load Jquery before main.js and typeahead.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax for the Bloodhound creation:

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.username);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {url: 'users.php?query=%QUERY'},

    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I have edited my answer. This is the complete syntax that is working for me (Twitter typeahead v0.10.5)

Comment: Well, for some reason it's still not working for me. I've double checked the users.php file and everything seems to be working from there. But once I type something in the 'input type text' it still doesn't auto complete.

Comment: do you monitor the AJAX query in a dev tool ? do you see any javascript error at excecution ?

Comment: I'm seeing an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined"